# Wordpress hook write to database before post save

Tags: wordpress, split, character, publish, before-save

I am beginner in wordpress and i would like to ask some help.
I need some hook , which will split the post after some number of characters (lets say 300) and will add my text after each split.I created filter hook, but i do not know how to create action hook - to write splitted  text with my text to database before save,publish  or edit action. This code works , but how to save to database?

```
function inject_ad_text_after_n_chars($content) {

  $enable_length = 30;
  global $_POST;
  if (is_single() && strlen($content) > $enable_length) {

$before_content = substr($content, 0, 30);
$before_content2 = substr($content, 30, 30);
$before_content3 = substr($content, 60, 30);
$before_content4 = substr($content, 90, 30);
$texta = '00000000000000000000';  

                 return $before_content . $texta . $before_content2 . $texta . $before_content3 . $texta . $before_content4;

}
  else {
    return $content;
  }
}

add_filter('the_content', 'inject_ad_text_after_n_chars');
```

Comment: It'sunclear what you're asking, but the usual valid WordPress response is probably the better one here: read the source code... (look for save_post)

Comment: although the accepted answer ( Shazzad ) answer is the right one for you ( and @Denis comment unclear to me ) I must ask this - why do you want to INSERT the posts to the DB like that , and not only use the split for DISPLAY ? ( I know it is more efficient in server terms , but a lot harder to maintain / revert )

Comment: Hi, Obmerk , i have special need for this.

Comment: For Denis save_post as i know is done after the post is saved , i need before save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `wp_insert_post_data` filter. In this function, to parameter is supplied for you to filter the data before it is inserted. You can use it like -

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'mycustom_data_filter', 10, 2);
function mycustom_data_filter($filtered_data, $raw_data){
    // do something with the data, ex

    // For multiple occurence
    $chunks = str_split($filtered_data['post_content'], 300);
    $new_content = join('BREAK HERE', $chunks);

    // For single occurence
    $first_content = substr($filtered_data['post_content'], 0, 300);
    $rest_content = substr($filtered_data['post_content'], 300);
    $new_content = $first_content . 'BREAK HERE' . $rest_content;

    // put into the data
    $filtered_data['post_content'] = $new_content;

    return $filtered_data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Shazzad very much for response , your code is working - splits and inserts text after 300 characters. How to modify the code to split and add text for the rest content (all post needs to be splitted)

Comment: You can use [str_split](http://www.php.net/str_split) ex `str_split($filtered_data['post_content'], 300)`

Comment: Shazzad, again thank you. One more question - how to change code to do not insert text in the middle of word? Thank you for your time.